# How do I reference a class into another class C++

Tags: c++, class, nested

I need some help referencing classes. I am fairly new to C++ and my class was given the assignment to make a contact list. Which i have already created but original the contact list had these member variables

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
string phones;
string emails;
string addresss;
```

Now the next assignment was to making the adress into a class. Now i created the header and .cpp file for the address I just don't know how to reintergate the address class into my contact class Here is my Full Codes for the Address header and .cpp class and contact header and .cpp class. I did not include my main program because I still havn't figured out how I am going to reference the Address into my Contact class

**Address header code :**

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_H
#define ADDRESS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Address
{
private:
string home2;
string street2;
string apt2;
string city2;
string state2;
string zip2;

public:

// Default constructor
// Initializes all variable to empty string
Address();

Address(string home, string street, string apt, string city, string state, string zip);

~Address(); // Deconstructor

// Accessor method for the home instance variable
string getHome() const;

// Accessor method for the street instance variable
string getStreet() const;

// Accessor method that returns apartment number
// if it is an apartment building, or "none" if
// it is a private house.
string getApt() const;

// Accessor method for the city instance variable
string getCity() const;

// Accessor method for the state instance variable
string getState() const;

// Accessor method for the zip instance variable
string getZip() const;

// Method that prints Address to console
void output() const;

// Method that solicits the information 
// Apartment will be set to "none" if it is a private house
// If it is an Apartment Building, method will solicit
// info about apartment 
void input();
};
#endif
```

**This is the Address .cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Address.h"


Address::Address() {

}

Address::Address(string home, string street, string apt, string city, string       
state, string zip) {
home2 = home;
street2 = street;
apt2 = apt;
city2 = city;
state2 = state;
zip2 = zip;

}

Address::~Address() {

}

string Address::getApt() const {
return apt2;
}
string Address::getCity() const {
return street2;
}
string Address::getHome() const {
return home2;
}
string Address::getStreet() const
{
return string();
}
string Address::getState() const {
return state2;
}
string Address::getZip() const {
return zip2;
}
```

**Okay and this is the Contact header file(*Notice there is still the string address thats from my previous code where i used address as a string i havent changed it yet untill i figure out how to reference the class*):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Address.h"

using namespace std;

// Function declarations 
#ifndef Contacts_H
#define Contacts_H



class Contacts {
private: // access modifiers    
     // All my member variables
string firstName;
string lastName;
string phones;
string emails;
string addresss;
Address& Addressreference;

public:
Contacts(); // default constructor

Contacts(string, string, string, string, string, Address); // overload  constructor

Contacts(string firstname, string lastname, string phone, string email,    string address, Address & reference);

~Contacts(); // Destructor function

             // Accessor Functions
string getfirstName() const;
string getlastName() const;
string getphones() const;
string getemails() const;
string getadresss() const;


};
#endif
```

**This is the Contact.cpp file code (again the string address is the temporary):**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Contacts.h"

// Function definitions

Contacts::Contacts()
{


}

Contacts::Contacts(string, string, string, string, string, Address) 
{
**strong text**}


Contacts::Contacts(string firstname, string lastname, string phone, string       email, string address, Address& reference) // overload constructor
{
firstName = firstname;
lastName = lastname;
phones = phone;
emails = email;
addresss = address;
Addressreference = reference
}

Contacts::~Contacts() {

}
string Contacts::getfirstName() const
{
return firstName;
};

string Contacts::getlastName() const
{
return lastName;
};
string Contacts::getphones() const
{
return phones;
};
string Contacts::getemails() const {
return emails;
};
string Contacts::getadresss() const
{
return addresss;
}
```

Comment: You don't want a reference _`Address& Addressreference;`_ but a plain member variable `Address address;`

Comment: That was just for testing purpose I actually have no idea how to referece in this case

Comment: You want a copy of `Address` in `Contact` (Note the singular BTW)

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need (and don't want) a reference to `Address` in your `Contact` class.

You simply use an embedded member variable of `Address`:

```
class Contact { // Note the singular term Contact. 
                // What you're designing isn't multiple contacts
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string phones;
    string emails;
    Address address; 
};
```

---

```
Contact::Contact
    ( string firstname_
    , string lastname_
    , string phones_
    , string emails_
    , const Address& address_) // overload constructor
: firstname(firstname_)
, lastname(lastname_)
, phones(phones_)
, emails(emails_)
, address(address_)
{}
```

It doesn't make much sense to share `Address` instances over `Contact` instances in most cases.

Comment: Well I thought I would need Address class in my contact class because I am required to implement a search engine via entering the contacts first and last name which outputs all their information including their address.

Comment: @Izine _"... which outputs all their information including their address."_ The `Address` information will be embedded that way.